# Number of users of Node Group is wrong

Tags: node-editor

Maybe this is a silly question but I have a Node Group in a Material, and the node displays "2" as the number of users, but I only have 1 sphere in the scene, that's all, which is used to test the material. There are no other objects. So I wonder why the 2 users instead of 1.

I searched before asking the question and all I found is this, but since I'm a newbie I don't really know if it's about the same thing or not:
https://developer.blender.org/T39552

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hello :). The *users* number is about materials. Perhaps there's another material with the same nodegroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the material, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and choose material.

This will select all the objects sharing that material.

If there are no selections either you have 2 material slots with the same material on your object or the object in question is in another scene.